# Can I check how many stamps I've collected in Mementos?

Tags: persona-5-royal

When navigating Mementos in Persona 5 Royal, you can collect stamps at the stamps stations for Jose's upgrades. Each time you collect a stamp, it tells you on screen how many stamps you've collected, and how many stamps there are total in the section of Mementos you are currently in.

Since there are more stamps to collect than there are floors in the respective sections of Mementos, you can't only rely on the one stamp station at the end of each floor, you have to find them randomly scattered in Mementos to complete that section.

I want to confirm that I found all the stamps from a previous section of Mementos, but am not sure if that is possible. I can't find a randomly generated stamp stand to have it display on screen how many I've found for that section (did I complete this section, or just bad luck?), and I can't seem to select the Stamp Book from key items for any additional information. Is there anywhere I can find the number of stamps collected per section of Mementos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just noticed that the same "number of stamps collected/number of total stamps" also displays on the Mementos Overview map, which can be accessed from Mementos entrance, or from any rest/end areas of the paths. Highlighting the paths will show this info under the path name.